# ionic4 ReactiveForms 'live' currency mask

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am looking for a live currency mask for Ionic4 type=angular to be implemented in a reactive form(s) i.e. as you type it automatically formats by adding the thousand separator.

I have used "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.1" with "text-mask-addons": "3.5.1" with success but it uses ngModel and template forms. Any solution for reactive forms or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a solution that works for Ionic 4 using pretty much any live mask including a customizable currency mask. It also works for reactive and template forms. If you are using ionic 4 install the angualr 2 text mask https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2  and follow the instructions i.e:

- npm i angular2-text-mask --save
- then:  import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask' into the module for the respective page(s);
- If you are using the currency mask then install the text mask add-on: npm i text-mask-addons --save
- You do not need to register this in a module, simply import into the page e.g. import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask'
- **Here is the big deal - DON'T use ion-input simply use the input tag in the html**
- I found it neater to use bootstrap forms and avoid ion-lists , ion-items etc (in other words use normal html e.g:

```
<label for="lb">Bond/ Rental?</label> 
<input formControlName = 'bond' class="form-control" id = "lb" 
    [textMask]="{mask:numberMask}" type ="tel" />
```

The page component code for the currency mask was a variable:

```
numberMask = createNumberMask({ prefix:'', thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ',', allowDecimal: true, decimalSymbol: '.' });
```

Also in the code was the standard form  - I used formbuilder e.g.

```
 this.housingForm = formBuilder.group({
      bond: ['' , Validators.compose([Validators.required])], 
      ......
```

I hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and I ended up using `(ionChange)`

**HTML**

```
<ion-input [formControlName]="NAME" (ionChange)="formatCurrency($event)"></ion-input>
```

**TS**

```
formatCurrency($event) {
    var aux = $event.target.value;
    aux = aux.replace(/\./g, "");
    aux = aux.replace(/\s/g, "");
    aux = aux.replace(/\$/g, "");
    aux = aux.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');
    if (aux.length > 1) aux = aux.replace(/^0+/, ''); /* Replace leading zeros */
    $event.target.value = "$" + aux;
}
```

It is a simple solution and it was the only solution I found that uses `ion-input`